# So, this function was supposed to use edge detection and apply sobel filter. But well It doesn't

Tags: c, image, filter

I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong. My intent is in title :)

This is the code I tried, and it clearly isn't working. It just print's 1 solid colour, also edges are not included yet. What part is wrong I can't figure it out what part of this code is wrong. It's just a function and it's in C.

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE edit[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            edit[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }


    for (int q = 1; q < height - 1; q++)
    {

        for (int w = 1; w < width - 1; w++)
        {

            int redEdit[9];
            int greenEdit[9];
            int blueEdit[9];


            for (int top = 0; top < 3; top++)
            {
                redEdit[top] += edit[q - 1][w - 1 + top].rgbtRed;
                greenEdit[top] += edit[q - 1][w - 1 + top].rgbtGreen;
                blueEdit[top] += edit[q - 1][w - 1 + top].rgbtBlue;
            }

            int midctr = 0;

            for (int mid = 3; mid < 6; mid++)
            {
                redEdit[mid] += edit[q][w - 1 + midctr].rgbtRed;
                greenEdit[mid] += edit[q][w - 1 + midctr].rgbtGreen;
                blueEdit[mid] += edit[q][w - 1 + midctr].rgbtBlue;

                midctr ++;
            }

            int topctr = 0;

            for (int top = 6; top < 9; top++)
            {
                redEdit[top] += edit[q + 1][w - 1 + topctr].rgbtRed;
                greenEdit[top] += edit[q + 1][w - 1 + topctr].rgbtGreen;
                blueEdit[top] += edit[q + 1][w - 1 + topctr].rgbtBlue;

                topctr ++;
            }

            int matrixgx[] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
            int matrixgy[] = {- 1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};

            int redEditgx[9];
            int greenEditgx[9];
            int blueEditgx[9];

            int redEditgy[9];
            int greenEditgy[9];
            int blueEditgy[9];

            for (int mtrx = 0; mtrx < 9; mtrx++)
            {
                redEditgx[mtrx] = redEdit[mtrx] * matrixgx[mtrx];
                greenEditgx[mtrx] = greenEdit[mtrx] * matrixgx[mtrx];
                blueEditgx[mtrx] = blueEdit[mtrx] * matrixgx[mtrx];

                redEditgy[mtrx] = redEdit[mtrx] * matrixgy[mtrx];
                greenEditgy[mtrx] = greenEdit[mtrx] * matrixgy[mtrx];
                blueEditgy[mtrx] = blueEdit[mtrx] * matrixgy[mtrx];
            }

            // now sum up the changes of gx and gt

            int redSumgx = 0;
            int greenSumgx = 0;
            int blueSumgx = 0;

            int redSumgy = 0;
            int greenSumgy = 0;
            int blueSumgy = 0;

            for (int sum = 0; sum < 9; sum++)
            {
                redSumgx += redEditgx[sum];
                greenSumgx += greenEditgx[sum];
                blueSumgx +=  blueEditgx[sum];

                redSumgy += redEditgy[sum];
                greenSumgy += greenEditgy[sum];
                blueSumgy += blueEditgy[sum];
            }

            int finalRed = round(sqrt(pow(redSumgx, 2) + pow(redSumgy, 2)));
            int finalGreen = round(sqrt(pow(greenSumgx, 2) + pow(greenSumgy, 2)));
            int finalBlue = round(sqrt(pow(blueSumgx, 2) + pow(blueSumgy, 2)));

            if (finalRed > 255)
            {
                finalRed = 255;
            }
            if (finalGreen > 255)
            {
                finalGreen = 255;
            }
            if (finalBlue > 255)
            {
                finalBlue = 255;
            }

            image[q][w].rgbtRed = finalRed;
            image[q][w].rgbtGreen = finalGreen;
            image[q][w].rgbtBlue = finalBlue;
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

I know this code is cancer please don't judge

Comment: Consider editing your question to add more details about the problem you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These arrays

```
int redEdit[9];
int greenEdit[9];
int blueEdit[9];
```

have not been initialised and hold arbitrary values. So when you execute statements such as

```
redEdit[top] += edit[q - 1][w - 1 + top].rgbtRed;
```

the sum is meaningless. You need

```
int redEdit[9] = { 0 };
int greenEdit[9] = { 0 };
int blueEdit[9] = { 0 };
```

Only static variables are implicitly initialised to `0`. Local (auto) variables are not.